# Removing index which is not common between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas.util.testing as testing
df = testing.makeDataFrame()
df
```

This this I have created 2 dataframes with one dataframe have 2 less lines than the original one.

This is `df` - Original

```
A   B   C   D
OdhGFPa5Kw  -0.686378   -1.210838   1.160708    0.903309
gelZFj4BG5  1.603112    1.852592    -0.065482   0.684566
mp3Aq5ueGD  0.254211    -0.788877   -0.626789   0.109116
pBtz9DHxUZ  -0.970632   0.982661    -0.463984   -0.123727
K28pzbdYcX  -1.311220   -2.121306   1.209484    -1.695901
71ZFgWaeDE  1.887420    0.337702    -0.176539   0.149089
alWOjkQ2eZ  1.997701    -0.354276   1.997802    -0.086803
```

This is `df1` - with 2 less lines

```
A   B   C   D
    OdhGFPa5Kw  -0.686378   -1.210838   1.160708    0.903309
    gelZFj4BG5  1.603112    1.852592    -0.065482   0.684566
    mp3Aq5ueGD  0.254211    -0.788877   -0.626789   0.109116
    pBtz9DHxUZ  -0.970632   0.982661    -0.463984   -0.123727
    K28pzbdYcX  -1.311220   -2.121306   1.209484    -1.695901
```

What I am trying to do is to remove all the rows which are not common between the two dataframes. To do this, we find the duplicate index in the two columns.

```
duplicates = set(df.index).intersection(df1.index)
```

Could you please advise how can I remove rows where index is not in the `duplicates` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the indices in place:

```
idx = df.index.difference(df1.index)
df.drop(idx, inplace=True)
```

If you want to create a new object:

```
idx = df.index.intersection(df1.index)
new_df = df.loc[idx]
```